# flutter dropdown menu string puşş and take double

Tags: flutter

```
i prepare a dropdown menu with 2 or more items 
İ want to take the double value and use it in a calculation
```

My entries are Aluminium 2.75 ----Steel 7.85 etc.
I define
String density_choose = "Steel 7.25";

```
  DropdownButton<String>(
                value: density_choose,
                items: density.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text("malzeme:$value"),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                onChanged: (var secilenVeri) {
                  setState(() {
                    density_choose = secilenVeri!;
                   
                  });
                },
              ),
```

My calculation

```
double sum = int.parse(kenar.text) *
                          int.parse(kenar.text) *
                          int.parse(yukseklik.text) *
                          int.parse(yukseklik.text) *double.parse(density_choose.split(" ")[2])/
                          1000000;
                      output = sum.toString();
```

I dont have any problem in syntax but I cant take the double

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?
Have you put break points ?
Try to split all the int.parse and double.parse into variables and print them before the calculation to see if you are getting the right values.

Comment: I dont take any errors.for the int values I can take the result for the density I cant take

Comment: there is 3 unit in string  [0]=Steel [1] ="" [2] =7.25 I cant take the value . for the int values ı can take print

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. It's coming from this `density_choose.split(" ")[2]`.

You should be getting the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUqyE.png) not the [2].

```
density_choose.split(" ")[1]
```

```
Since:
density_choose = 'Steel 7.25';

Then:
density_choose.split(" ") = ['Steel', '7.25']
density_choose.split(" ")[0] = 'Steel';
density_choose.split(" ")[1] = '7.25';
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works I think when split space is also an item

Comment: Happy it works.
Please upvote and accept the response as the solution to close the question. Thanks